# Convert JSON schema to Flink DDL

Tags: recursion, apache-flink, jsonschema, flink-sql

How can I convert a JSON schema to a Flink DDL statement?

For example, given the following JSON schema which has a nested object property

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "i": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "p": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "i": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "p1": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "i": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to be converted to the following Flink SQL DDL statement using the [row](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/types/#row) type

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_nested (
    name STRING,
    id STRING,
    i INTEGER,
    p ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER, p1 ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER))
) WITH (
    'connector'='print'
);
```

I tried to iterate through the `properties` field but I don't know what to do whenever I encounter an `object` type. My guess is that I need to do it recursively but I don't know the exact steps.

```java
private static String traverse(JsonNode rootNode) {
    JsonNode properties = rootNode.get("properties");
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = properties.fields();
    // columnNameType will contain the "columnName dataType", for example
    // "name STRING"
    // "id STRING"
    // "i INTEGER"
    // "p ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER, p1 ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER))"
    List<String> columnNameType = new ArrayList<>();
    while (fields.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> next = fields.next();
        String key = next.getKey();
        JsonNode value = next.getValue();
        String type = value.get("type").asText();

        if(type.equals("object")) {
            // recurse???
        } else {
            columnNameType.add(key+" "+type);
        }
    }
    // this should return a formatted string like
    /*
        name STRING,
        id STRING,
        i INTEGER,
        p ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER, p1 ROW(name STRING, id STRING, i INTEGER))
    */
    return String.join(",\n",  columnNameType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can be a good starting point. Note that I've simplified the JSON structure as well:

```json
{
  "name": "string",
  "i": "integer",
  "p" : {
    "prop1": "string",
    "prop2": "integer",
    "prop3": {
      "prop4": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```java
private static String traverse(JsonNode jsonNode, boolean topLevel) {
  List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

  jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb
        .append('`')
        .append(entry.getKey())
        .append("` ");

    if (entry.getValue().isObject()) {
      sb
          .append("ROW(")
          .append(traverse(entry.getValue(), false))
          .append(")");
    } else {
      sb.append(entry.getValue().asText().toUpperCase());
    }
    fields.add(sb.toString());
  });

  return String.join(topLevel ? ",\n" : ", ", fields);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```java
traverse(rootNode, true)
```

Produces the following output:

```
`name` STRING,
`i` INTEGER,
`p` ROW(`prop1` STRING, `prop2` INTEGER, `prop3` ROW(`prop4` STRING))
```